# Confused about output in student project

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby through The Odin Project. I was tasked with building a Caesar Cipher program, and I've been banging my head against this problem all day. I finally wrote what I thought would be a working program, but I don't understand the output. Here's the Git: https://github.com/PAMulligan/caesar_cipher.git. If anyone has any insight into where I went wrong, I would love some help.

Comment: Hey @DudeMontag. Welcome to SO. What don't you understand about the output? If you need some help, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Well, the program isn't doing what I expected. Instead of outputting an encrypted version of the input string, it just prints each letter of the string on a separate line.

Comment: If you wonder why you are getting downvoted, Stack Overflow isn't "fix it for me" place, you are supposed to ask about specific problem, in your case that could be something like "why this piece of code prints output on separate lines <<piece of code here>>"

Comment: I thought I was being specific, but I guess I was doing it wrong. I didn't actually want anyone to "fix it for me", I just wanted some advice, but passive-aggressive answers are always fun, I guess.

Comment: Post your code ... in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me ruin it for you...

Your basic logic seems both sound and overly complex at the same time.

Here is some input:

1. You defined a lot of methods for tasks that already exist. Always assume that Ruby has you covered, for any task you need - even if you're wrong, searching through the documentation will open your mind to different options at your disposal.
2. You ignored the fact that the String is UTF8 encoded. so `c.ord + cypher` might give you an unexpected value that isn't UTF8 valid. Also, while `'д'.ord == 1076`, you should be aware that `1076.chr` would raise a `RangeError` exception.
3. Assuming you expected ASCII values (using `.ord` and `.chr`), we should take into account the fact that bytes are limited to 8 bits (or one octet) - so the highest number for an encrypted byte is 255.
4. It is better to confine the methods to a namespace using a module - which I will **not** do here, since I have no idea at what point you are in your studies.

The Caesar algorithm:

1. Turn the string into an array of numbers, each representing a letter... Oh wait, there's a built in method that does that.[`String#bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-bytes) returns an array of integers representing the value of each byte in the binary string.
2. Iterate the array of numbers to change the array by adding the cypher number (use [`Array#map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) to change the array in-place). Here we just need to remember that bytes have an upper limit value of 255, so we should use the 'modulu' method [`Fixnum#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-25).
3. Now we just need to convert the array of bytes (with the new value) back to a string... Now we know that the String has a method to turn the string into an array of bytes, so it is only logical that the inverse would also be true - I would go with the [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) method.

Here's the gist of it as a sketch:

```
 some_string.bytes.map! {|i| (i +/- cypher) % 255 } .pack 'C*'
 # the +/- refers to the question of encoding vs. decoding and won't work.
```

All you need is one line, really.

I would recommend that you assume that the language you use has almost any method you would ever need. So if you need to perform an action - such as taking a unicode string and converting it into an array of numbers (vs. the limit I introduced, which is a binary octet limit of 255) - Ruby has you covered.

Now, since my answer probably ruined the challenge to some degree - allow me to offer you back the challenge.

Rewrite the solution I offered so that it would work for UTF8 strings (the standard encoding), allowing you a stronger encryption as the cypher's limit will be the higher UTF8 encoding limit rather than the 255 limit for a byte.

**EDIT**

Since the "one line" concept made the answer look more advanced than it was, here's what that code would look like if it was multi-line:

```
# the encryption method takes a string and a number
def caesar_encrypt string, cypher
   # string.bytes will return an array of numbers.
   # The numbers are between 0 and 255 (8 bits or 1 byte)
   # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte
   array = string.bytes
   # using the Array.map! changes the array in place.
   # it's the same as: array = array.map {...}
   # the format: { ... } is a one line block, similar to the do ... end.
   array.map! do |i|
      (i + cypher) % 255
   end
   # array.pack is used for taking objects in an array and transforming them
   # to a string. the 'C*' means we are packing bytes together to a string.
   # There are more options such as 'N*' which would pack 32 bit numbers into
   # a string. It's a great way to save or manipulate binary data,
   # which is at the core of all digital data.
   array.pack 'C*'
end
def caesar_decrypt
   caesar_encrypt string, (0-cypher)
end
```

Notice that `Array#pack` might be a bit advanced and using your original solution will also work... now that we are using bytes, `Fixnum#chr` should work as expected.

```
def caesar_encrypt string, cypher
   array = string.bytes
   array.map! do |i|
      (i + cypher) % 255
   end
   out = ""
   array.each {|c| out << c.chr}
   out
end
```

Comment: First of all, good answer. Just one thing: "All you need is one line, really". Not a very good example for a beginner. This one line you wrote have some ruby concepts that may not be so easy for a beginner to understand (as he said, he's learning  ruby). You have the "!", method chaining and block going on in this one line. And by the way, loved the "let me offer you a challenge back" part.

Comment: This is a little more advanced than I understand at the moment, although I do appreciate the help. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 reputation yet :) Thank you for the advice though, the reason I like Ruby is that there are "Ruby ways" of doing things, and I intend to learn those ways!

Comment: DudeMontag - My ruby code was a bit condensed and used `Array#pack`, which made it look more advanced than it should have been. I updated my answer and hope it's more helpful now. BTW, you can always "accept" answers to your own questions since they are **your** questions. @lcguida Thank you for pointing these issues out.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I can help with. There are three lines giving you grief right now.

**The first problem is line 33 `if i == (65..90)`**

> Right now, that line is asking if i is equal to the ENTIRE range of numbers between 65 and 90, which of course it isn't. This line is returning `false`, and your `if` branch is never even being executed. This is why you are getting back the same letters you started with!
>
> What you are looking for is Ruby's `between?(a,b)` method where `a` is the bottom of the range and `b` is the top. So, change that line to:
>
> `if i.between?(65, 90)`
>
> and you are good to go.

**The second line giving you grief is line 39 `elsif i == (97..122)`**

> This line is a problem for the exact same reason as the first one. Fix it in the same way.

**The third line giving you grief is line 14 `puts convert_to_char(cipher_array)`.**

> Your `convert_to_char` method is returning an array, and when Ruby is asked to `puts` an array, it just pops each item off on its own line. Use Ruby's `join` method, which joins all of the elements together into a string. You can use this by changing line 14 to:
>
> `puts convert_to_char(cipher_array).join`
>
> Note, you could also add `join` to line 58 instead and get the same result. Try it out and see!

I hope this helps you out, and keep on learning!

Comment: Thanks! I used puts because I read that it automatically calls to_s on an object, which I thought would be useful for the output, but I can see why that was a wrong call. I would upvote your comment, but I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used the advice given by Dan Phillips, namely changing my "if i == ..." statements to "if i.between?" statements, and it worked perfectly!